# JavaFX freeze window

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I encountered a problem when I filter a treeView (long process) my application freezes. I tried to do this in a separate thread (Thread), but then I got the error "Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-5"

```
void InitBtnFind() {
        //Event Button Search
        btnFind.setOnAction(event -> {
            newFind();
            if (Config.isRoot()) {
                String finalSFilterExt = filterExt.getText();
                String finalSearchW = searchWord.getText();
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    try {
                        // imitation of work
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        fileView.setRoot(treeView.filterChanged(finalSFilterExt, finalSearchW));
                    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("lol");
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

You can give a sample code to solve my problem.
P.s. Do not lower my reputation, I am really interested in this matter

P.s. my attempt to do this with thread

```
//Event Button Search
        btnFind.setOnAction(event -> {
            newFind();
            if (Config.isRoot()) {
                String finalSFilterExt = filterExt.getText();
                String finalSearchW = searchWord.getText();
                if (findThread != null && findThread.isAlive())
                    findThread.interrupt();
                findThread = new Thread(() -> {
                    try {
                        fileView.setRoot(treeView.filterChanged(finalSFilterExt, finalSearchW));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("lol");
                    });
                findThread.setName("findThread");
                findThread.setDaemon(true);
                findThread.start();
            }
            System.out.println("kek");
        });
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. and use Java naming conventions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **fixed** it this way, I don’t know how correct it is. But it worked for me. I hope it will be useful.

```
  //Event Button Search
        btnFind.setOnAction(event -> {
            newFind();
            if (Config.isRoot()) {
                String finalSFilterExt = filterExt.getText();
                String finalSearchW = searchWord.getText();
                if (findThread != null && findThread.isAlive())
                    findThread.interrupt();
                findThread = new Thread(() -> {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        System.out.println("++++++++++++++");
                        var q =treeView.filterChanged(finalSFilterExt, finalSearchW);
                        Platform.runLater(()->{fileView.setRoot(q);});
                    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    });
                findThread.setName("findThread");
                findThread.setDaemon(true);
                findThread.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Safe enough only if treeView.filterChanged doesn't modify anything that's related to a control active in the scenegraph ...